# PHP JSON BigInt encoding

Tags: php, azure

I have array like:

```
$array = ['id' => '76561198165327575'];
```

And I need it to work in JavaScript on client side. So I'm trying to encode it with `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

And getting result like:

```
{"id":7.6561198165328e+16}
```

But it should be:

```
{"id":76561198165327575}
```

What is wrong?

(Azure, Windows, 5.6)

Comment: you're probably on a 32bit PHP, which means you can't have anything larger than 2**32-1 for an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` basically tells the encoder "If it looks like a number, encode it as a number":

```
php > $x = '123456789012234567890';
php > echo json_encode($x, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
1.2345678901223e+20
php > echo json_encode($x);
"123456789012234567890"
```

And since your number exceeds the representable range for an INT on your platform, you get a float instead.

Comment: I thought it's just stripping quots from all numeric values... Is there any way to fix it? (Except custom PHP on Azure)

Comment: not really. you could post-process the json string to remove the quotes, since it'll be just a plaintext string at that point, but then you risk mangling the json.

Comment: + Answer is spot on. As an aside, you may want to look into `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: good call, I keep forgetting that option's there, since it's not mentioned on the encode() page, only in the json constants one. But unfortunately, it still does the same thing - encodes the bigint as a string, not a raw number.

Comment: Indeed, it's the opposite of what the OP intended. It does preserve the precision though. Albeit as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the bounds of integer on your 32-bit system. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) describes that when this occurs, the number is converted to a float.

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you encode in JSON objects with large numbers (greater than PHP_MAX_INT), you will always end up getting a floating point value. The only solution is to store them in the object/array as string (that you already) and not use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (but convert the string to a number on the client) or write your own encoding routine.